# python auto repeating serial data

Tags: python, tkinter, serial-port

Hello I have the bellow code which sends a character to the serial port depending on the state of a check button in tkinter. This works well but I require the character to be repeatability sent over the serial port (every 10 seconds or so) regardless to whether or not the state of the check button has changed. I have tried adding in a while loop but this makes the program crash. Any help would be grand.

(This is a small section of a larger code, as it stands it works as described above)

```
def setCheckButtonText():
    if varCheckButton.get():
         ser.write(bytes('L'))
    else:
         ser.write(bytes('H'))       

def setCheckButtonText2():
    if varCheckButton2.get():
        ser.write(bytes('F'))
    else:
       ser.write(bytes('O'))

def setCheckButtonText3():
    if varCheckButton3.get():
        ser.write(bytes('N'))
    else:
        ser.write(bytes('Y'))


ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)

varCheckButton = tk.IntVar()
tkCheckButton = tk.Checkbutton(
    mGui,
    variable=varCheckButton,
    command=setCheckButtonText)
tkCheckButton.place(x=60, y=50)

varCheckButton2 = tk.IntVar()
tkCheckButton = tk.Checkbutton(
    mGui,
    variable=varCheckButton2,
    command=setCheckButtonText2)
tkCheckButton.place(x=60, y=90)

varCheckButton3 = tk.IntVar()
tkCheckButton = tk.Checkbutton(
    mGui,
    variable=varCheckButton3,
    command=setCheckButtonText3)
tkCheckButton.place(x=60, y=130)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to capsule sending and setting the variables.

In your methods, you can just set the appropriate variables to the characters instead of sending them directly.
In another method, you can use those characters to send them to the serial port. You can use `after` to call a method after a delay.

```
def send():
    #Send variables here
    mGui.after(10000, send)

mGui.after(10000, send)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I should have said in the OP im new to all this. how can apply this to my code? would this repeat the characters or just delay them being sent?

Comment: I don't wanna explain everything here, but you can replace the `ser.write` calls with `char1 = bla`. It'd be even better if you'd use a list instead. In `send` you get the list as a parameter or you're using attributes so you can send them as you did before.